# Add Spellcheck Dictionary to Abiword 3.0

Tags: lubuntu, language-support, spell-checking, abiword

I am working on Lubuntu 14.04 with Abiword 3.0.0 and with the pre-installed version only the spell-check for English came along. I can switch to other languages within the program, but then the spell-checking isn't working.

I checked different forums, but didn't find a straightforward solution. I downloaded the ispell "hash" files (+encoding file) for French and German. But now I don't know where (in which folder location) to put them or how to use or properly install them. The location info from this help page doesn't seem to correspond anymore (http://www.abisource.com/help/en-US/info/infospelling.html)

But maybe that's also not the way to go and I can achieve spell-checking of these languages in a different way. How could this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Testing with version 3.0.2 in 18.04.

Without having German or Italian support installed on my system I was able to switch to German and Italian, select them from the "Set language" setting (right-click outside text within document or under "Tools") and use spelling successfully.

[image]

[image]

Make default, press Enter.

It seems the OP already did that but then the spelling didn't work. That may be true or may be an impression coming from the fact that the setting above is somewhat buggy and the selection is not followed as expected, or rather the selection is a bit difficult to make - I had to repeat a few times in order to get the correct selection. It seemed to me that the "Make default" option is not immediately followed, in which case I made sure that my text intended for correction was *selected*, and then right-clicked while it was selected, and then chose "Set language", with double-click on the language name. To see which corrector is selected for different parts of text, click text and look at right-bottom of the Abiword window.

[image]

Maybe the 18.04 comes with installed aspell dictionaries that were lacking in previous ubuntu-s. And indeed, the instructions at the address linked in the question are partially outdated. There is no `/usr/local/share/AbiSuite-2.0/dictionary/` in the 3.x version. There is `/usr/share/abiword-3.0/` but without any dictionaries. I guess the 3.x program uses some dictionaries at system level, but I am not sure it's the aspell ones, because in Synaptic I only see `aspell` and `aspell-en` installed (While German and Italian spellcheck is working without having those language added to the system).

In order to install aspell dictionaries they should be available in Synaptic or similar tools. In order to install them manually, go [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html), download the archive, open a terminal within the resulting directory and run

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

But that's not what made it work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Open **Language Support** (in Menu -> Preferences), and install those languages you want to be available. The files you install that way will include dictionaries for spell checking.

Comment: Language Support? Where? In Abiword? There is no menu for that.

Comment: @A.B.: It's not in Abiword. I'm not a Lubuntu user, but I think it is under "System settings" or something like that.

Comment: Why do you answer if you do not know it?

Comment: @A.B.: The answer is correct. Even if I'm not able to provide the detailed guidance as regards the menu structure, it may well be sufficient for a Lubuntu user. Otherwise someone else can fill in, right?

Comment: It is located in Menu->Preferences->Language Support.

Comment: The OP asks how to add new multiple spelling check dictionaries to Abiword, that can be then switched within the application (the way we can in Libreoffice Writer), not how to add new languages to the system and use one of them as main for Abiword, which then cannot be switched from within the application if they are not available there. Without having German installed in system Language Settings I was able to use German spelling check, therefore Abiword uses other source for its dictionaries (maybe absent in 14.04, but not in 18.04) than what the answer above is suggesting.